# Can I disable this Dell PremierColor feature?

Tags: malware, oem

Is it possible to turn these blue boxes off?

They pop up whenever I drag a browser window.

[image]

Comment: What kind of computer do you have? I at first thought it was some kind of Windows 10 tip or something related to snapping Windows. I then came across this [article](http://www.tenforums.com/general-discussion/31267-windows-10-how-disable-snap-popup-when-you-move-window.html) and it seems *Dell PremierColor* was the culprit for this.

Comment: @DrZoo it's a Dell laptop alright!!

Comment: Well I'd say remove that program and you should be good to go

Comment: @DrZoo You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to disable that stupid screen splitter...

- Open Dell PremierColor
- Advanced
- Uncheck *Display Splitter on*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Upon looking into the solution, I came across this [forum post](http://www.tenforums.com/general-discussion/31267-windows-10-how-disable-snap-popup-when-you-move-window.html), where someone had your same issue.

This feature is caused by *Dell PremierColor*. Removing the program will stop the snap suggestions from popping up.

Why Dell thought this was a good feature? I have no idea.